# Padding or shifting a multi-dimensional array

Tags: r

How can I simply pad (append/prepend) a slice of `NA`'s to a (say) 3D array along (say) dimension 2?

Suppose the initial array is given as

```
A <- array(1:8,c(2,2,2))
```

I initially thought this would work:

```
cbind(A,NA)
```

but it results in an 8x2 matrix instead of a 2x3x2 array. I then tried

```
abind(A,NA,along=2)
```

but that results in an error.

I'm hoping there is a much simpler solution than

```
dimSlice <- dim(A)
dimSlice[2] <- 1
abind(A,array(NA,dimSlice),along=2)
```

## Background

This padding happens as part of a "remove slice and pad opposite side" operation that shifts an array by one position along some dimension, filling in with `NA` elements at the vacated positions. The one-dimensional equivalent would be, for example, `c(A[-1],NA)` for vector `A`, If there is a simple way to accomplish such an operation without an explicit padding sub-operation, that would be even better.

Comment: Perhaps, you could subset with `NA`? `A[, c(1:dim(A)[2], NA), ]`. Could that fit your "remove and pad"?

Comment: @alexis_laz So I'd shift left with `A[,c(2:ncol(A),NA),]`. That seems perfect. Could you put it into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsetting with `NA`s results in `NA`s (`?Extract`):

```
v = 1:3; m = matrix(1:4, 2, 2); a = array(1:6, c(2, 2, 2))
v[c(NA, 1)]
#[1] NA  1
m[, c(2, NA)]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3   NA
#[2,]    4   NA
a[, c(1, 2, NA), ]
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3   NA
#[2,]    2    4   NA
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    1   NA
#[2,]    6    2   NA
```

So, to pad with `NA`s, we could subset using the appropriate indices. Putting the above in a more general function to append/prepend "n" indices with `NA` in dimension "k" of an array:

```
pad = function(x, k, n = 1L, append = TRUE)
{
    dims = replicate(length(dim(x)), substitute(), simplify = FALSE)
    if(append) dims[[k]] = c((n + 1):dim(x)[[k]], rep_len(NA, n))
    else dims[[k]] = c(rep_len(NA, n), 1:(dim(x)[[k]] - n))
    do.call("[", c(list(x), dims))
}

arr = array(1:24, c(3, 2, 2, 2))
pad(arr, 1, 2, FALSE)
pad(arr, 2)
```

Comment: @tennenrishin I have nothing against this function - it's perfectly fine. But someone looking at this answer without reading the comment would have no clue what's going on here (and fwiw I was confused, *with* reading the comment). So this is a very low quality answer from my point of view.

Comment: @eddi Can you improve on it?

Comment: @eddi : are you referring to more extensive explanation? you're probably right; will try to fix it

Comment: your idea to use `abind` is correct, just that you did not use it in the right way. Check my answer

Comment: OK, I think I probably missed the second part of your Q or it's a new update. Initially you mentioned `abind(A,NA,along=2)` threw error I did not notice you fixed the dimension issue.